# String Initialization for Dummies

Tags: android, string

OK I am messing something simple up here.

I have three Classes all within an Activity:

```
public class ActivityUserAccountCreate extends Activity implements
        OnClickListener {

}

private class postToHttps extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            createUserAccount();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public void createUserAccount() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
...
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

Log.d("Posting Username", usernameFinal);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "usernameFinal"));
...

}
```

In my Activity class I initialize three Strings which are in the layout. Basically the user enters their username in a EditText.  The strings are = to get the text form the field.  That all works fine, but I am trying to use those same Strings in the createUserAccount().  I believe that the Strings are null at that point, so do I have to reinitialize these same three strings again in the createUserAccount()?  If so, should I do it the same way that I did in in the Activity Class?

Thanks

OK I have edited according to the recommendation below, to:

```
...
new postToHttps().execute(usernameFinal,passwordFinal,userEmail);
...

private class postToHttps extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String usernameFinal = params[0];
            String passwordFinal = params[1];
            String userEmail = params[2];

            try {
                createUserAccount(usernameFinal, passwordFinal, userEmail);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

public void createUserAccount(String usernameFinal, String passwordFinal, String userEmail) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    String uri = "editedout.php";
    Log.d("Action", "Posting user data to php");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost getMethod = new HttpPost(uri);
    Log.d("Posting Location", uri);
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    Log.d("Posting Username", usernameFinal);
    nameValuePairs
            .add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", usernameFinal));

    Log.d("Posting Pass", passwordFinal);
    nameValuePairs
            .add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passwordFinal));

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", userEmail));

    getMethod
            .setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
    client.execute(getMethod);
    Log.d("Action", "Finished Posting Data to PHP");
}
```

but am getting a crash.  it looks like it is crashing in the doInBackground, but am still learning to read the LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to be reinitializing anything, but if you are trying to pass in three Strings into your `AsyncTask`, I suggest taking advantage of the variable arguments used in `doInBackground(String... params)`.

For example:

```
...
private class PostToHttps extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String username = params[0];
        String firstName = params[1];
        String lastName = params[2];

        createUserAccount(username, firstName, lastName);
    }
...

PostToHttps httpsTask = new PostToHttps();
httpsTask.execute(usernameEditText.getText().toString(),
                  firstNameEditText.getText().toString(),
                  lastNameEditText.getText().toString);

...

public void createUserAccount(String username, String firstName, String lastName)
    throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
...
```

Comment: When you call `execute(...)` on your postToHttps task, are you passing in the username, password, and email strings?

Comment: new postToHttps().execute();

Comment: You will want to pass in the three strings from your user into that execute function. In the example above, I'm retrieving the text from three `EditText` fields and passing the values in the `execute(...)` function, to be used in `doInBackground(...)`.

Comment: Ok I changed it as suggested, but it is still crashing.  Cant figure why, it seems right.

Comment: I have cleared the error.  The POST runs smooth BUT no data is passed to the php form.  I already know the form is good if I do not use strings as a substitute.  This means that the post is sending null data or something.  What do you think is wrong?

Comment: Doing further testing on the createUserAccount shows that the Strings are passed to this method ok.  If I comment out the array list and leave just the Log.d then the String values are correct in the log. This means that I have a problem in the array list.  I don't see it